# Why do my particles in a gravity model repel with each other?

Tags: python, processing, simulation, particles, physics-engine

So I'm trying to build a simple particle interactions model with gravity (later on i want to make it more complex, but not for now).

I'm working on Processing, specifically processing.py. I've created 2 files, one is the main with the setup and draw functions. The other one is the Particle class, where i define the particle properties and laws of gravity. For the gravity I'm using Newton F = G*m1*m2 / r^2 .

This is the main file:

```
#MAIN --> simulation of a particles system influenced by gravity and temperatures
from particle import Particle

num_particles = 20
particle_array = []

show = False #To show the distance with particles that are interacting (LATER)

def setup():
    size(1000, 600)
    for p in range(num_particles):
        p = Particle()
        particle_array.append(p)
    
def draw():
    background(255)
    
    for i in range(len(particle_array)):
        particle_array[i].display()
        #I'm creating another array without the particle considered in the loop. So i can confront the first one with
        #every other particle except itself.
        part_array = [elem for elem in particle_array if elem != particle_array[i]]
        #check interaction with every particles
        for k in range(len(part_array)):
            particle_array[i].check_interaction(part_array[k], show)
    
    #different loops to first determine the acceleration without changing positions
    #and later on updating the positions
    for elem in particle_array: 
        elem.update()
        
    #fill(173, 164, 164)
    #rect(10, 10, 20, 20) #Show Interactions box
```

This is the class:
https://pastebin.com/nJJE45Rs

So what is happening? When I start the simulation something strange happens with the coordinates.

I got a "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer". I tried to see from what it was coming and it seems that some coordinates casually became NaN and the int() function crash because it can't do the conversion from NaN to int. So it is very strange. (SOLVED, see in the comment)

Also it seems like the particles behave in a very strange way, it doesn't seems like a force of gravity. They seem to repel instead of attracting.

For the math of this model I've begun getting the module of the acceleration from the force. Then, assuming that the acceleration vector points to the other particle (the one on which the interaction is being calculated) I have to determine the angle from the x-axis that I will use to calculate Ax and Ay as in here:

```
angle = acos((x2 - x1) / r) #Orientation of the acceleration vector
            print("Angle: " + str(angle) + "x1, y1, x2, y2: " + str(x1) +" "+ str(y1) +" "+ str(x2) +" "+ str(y2), "R: " + str(r))
            #print("New Angle: " + str(angle), "X1; Y1, X2, Y2: " + str(x1) +str(y1) + str(x2) + str(y2))
            ax = a * cos(angle)
            ay = a * sin(angle)
            self.a.add(ax, ay, 0) #update Acceleration vector
```

I've used the acos function like that because in a rect triangle:

```
A = Point (x1, y1)
B = Point (x2, y2)
AB * cos(angle) = (x2 - x1)
```

But I don't know, things seems to fail.

Comment: I'm not a python buff, but the first thing I'd do would be to print `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` and see what they contains. There will probably be something to understand there, even if it's just that they are fine. Tag me if you do and add the information to your post, so I can know that you updated it.

Comment: @laancelot I have already done that. And often the code runs smoothly, but sometimes, out of nowhere, 2 of the four values, especially x2 and y2 become NaN. Even if I force them to be 0 and not NaN.

Comment: Ok, please check for the following possibilities in your code regarding numbers that are or affects the values which arrives NaN in the method that crashes: `dividing by zero`, `sqrt(num) where num < 0`, `number is not a float`. You can check for NaN in different ways, amongst other things (in pseudocode): `if num != num then return` may let you skip the exceptions if there is no other way around it.

Comment: @laancelot Oh, I think this could be very useful. Thank you very much I'll check it asap.

Comment: Ok, I've found the error. It is a Math error. I'm passing a value grater than 1 to the asin function, and that is not possible. So the function return a NaN value that cause the problems in the next cycle. This was caused by the int() applied to the r assignation. R was aproximated and this resulted in a Value greater than one. But I think the physics is very broken. Particles seems to repel instead of being attracted to one another. Arghhh!

Comment: Congratulations on pinpointing the issue! Reminds me that I had an application crash for a similar impossible trigonometry issue while calculating GPS coordinates versus light coverage. I suggest that you make a new post with the current issue if you want to better your chances at help.

Comment: I've edited the question. Don't know if I did wrong. @laancelot

Comment: You did good, but most people won't scroll back to re-read questions they already read once, so you would have better chances at help with a new post. Also, a post that concentrate on a specific problem (like speaking about the physics and not the NaN thing) will let them concentrate on what matters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend avoiding angles altogether. I find vectors much easier to work with. If you want to know the angle later, you can use the `PVector.heading()` method which outputs the angle between the vector and the `(0, 1)` vector.

If I were making this from scratch, I would convert the positions to vectors as well. Since that would influence your other methods, here is how I would adapt your code:

### (DISCLAIMER: I don't use processing in Python, so I couldn't run this to check for errors. Just comment if you run into any issues)

```py
def check_interaction(self, p2, show_interactions):
    r_vec = PVector(p2.x - self.x, p2.y - self.y) #vector from self to other particle
    if r.mag() < 200:
        if show_interactions: #draw the line
            stroke(110)
            line(self.x, self.y, p2.x, p2.y)
        if 1 < r.magSq():
            grav_acc = G * p2.mass / r_vec.magSq() #acceleration due to the other particle
            r_vec.setMag(grav_acc) #Change magnitude of r_vec so it's now the acceleration vector (due to p2)
            self.a = self.a.add(r_vec) #update acceleration
```

If you want to convert

```
self.x = random(screen_width)
self.y = random(screen_height)
```

to

```
self.pos = PVector(random(screen_width), random(screen_height))
```

in `def __init__(self)`, you can define `r_vec` like this:

```
r_vec = p2.pos.sub(self.pos)
```